# Combining ClickThrough and SEO

Tags: seo

Has anyone perform a research on the effect of using redirects to SEO?

My situation:

I have a link, say `<a href="click.htm?id=1"></a>`, the target page will record a clickthrough through server-side code and send a redirect response for the original URL to the user agent. How does this may affect SEO?

In contrast, Google search result is using mousedown JS that calls the clickthrough address instead of redirection. So the original link is kept on the HTML.

On another web site, when a link is clicked an image is downloaded to record the clickthrough.

So the ultimate question is: how do you accurately record clickthroughs without affecting SEO (if it affect anything at all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a PHP file which records the click through to a database and then have it do a 301 redirect to your target URL, this will preserve link juice and act as a completely normal link without bloating your page with JavaScript or anything.

```
  header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header ('Location: http://example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an intermediate link manager to direct the traffic. Don't go directly to the address. In this way you can manage everything after the click it received. It also makes it easy to move things.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use rel="canonical" tag on web page.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with zuk1, but i also some suggestion :

If your old page important and it's match with new page then you should 301 redirect, so your old page reputation stay into new page.

And If your old page content duplicate with new page then you need to "canonical" tag put in old page.

And If your old page not important and you don't want to redirect then you need to 404 not found page for user, with instruction OR you can put "noindex,nofollow" tag in the page, so google consider that your page no need to index and follow in search engines like google.